# ggdendrogram labels

Tags: r

How can I change the labels of the dendrogram to them matching name in the list? At the moment I only get the list number.

Code:

```
library(IncDTW)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro) 

A <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 50, ncol = 1)
B <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 75, ncol = 1)
C <- matrix(25:49, nrow = 25, ncol = 1)
D <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 50, ncol = 1)
treeList <- list(A,B,C,D)

names(treeList)[1] <- "A"
names(treeList)[2] <- "B"
names(treeList)[3] <- "C"
names(treeList)[4] <- "D"

result <- dtw_dismat(treeList, dist_method = "norm2", return_matrix = F)
distMatrixResult <- result$dismat
hc <- hclust(distMatrixResult, method = "average")
ggdendrogram(hc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loosing your labels right after `dtw_distmat` function:

```
$dismat
         1    2        3        4
1 0.000000 2.60 4.013333 0.000000
2 2.600000 0.00 6.510000 2.600000
3 4.013333 6.51 0.000000 4.013333
4 0.000000 2.60 4.013333 0.000000
```

You can transform output of `hclust` with `dendro_data` function. Then you can change labels of this transformed object:

```
hc <- dendro_data(hc)
dict <- setNames(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 1:4)
hc$labels$label <- sapply(hc$labels$label, function(x) dict[[as.character(x)]])
```

After this `ggdendrogram(hc)` will return plot with labels.

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW is there a way to automatically set the names without  needing the dict <- setNames(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 1:4)?

Comment: It's because `dtw_distmat` function is losing names. Otherwise labels would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing me to this new feature. I will consider it in the next release of **IncDTW**. In the meanwhile a quick fix would be to do the following:

```
a <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
a <- a + t(a)
as.dist(a)
b <- usedist::dist_setNames(a, letters[1:3])
b

# where dist_setnames() does the following:
dm <- as.matrix(d)
dimnames(dm) <- list(nm, nm)
stats::as.dist(dm)
```

So `dist_setnames()` converts the dist.object to a matrix, which is fine for small lists of time series, but maybe a problem if the distance matrix gets big.