# ggdendrogram labels - automatic set the names

Tags: r

Based on a post [ggdendrogram labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593085/ggdendrogram-labels) I tried to change the dict deceleration to dict <- names(treeList). It does not work. why? can it be fixed?

Code:

```
library(IncDTW)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro) 

A <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 50, ncol = 1)
B <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 75, ncol = 1)
C <- matrix(25:49, nrow = 25, ncol = 1)
D <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 50, ncol = 1)
treeList <- list(A,B,C,D)

names(treeList)[1] <- "A"
names(treeList)[2] <- "B"
names(treeList)[3] <- "C"
names(treeList)[4] <- "D"

result <- dtw_dismat(treeList, dist_method = "norm2", return_matrix = F)
distMatrixResult <- result$dismat
hc <- hclust(distMatrixResult, method = "average")
hc <- dendro_data(hc)
dict <- names(treeList)
hc$labels$label <- sapply(hc$labels$label, function(x) dict[[as.character(x)]])
ggdendrogram(hc)
```

Comment: While your `dict` is just a character vector, the one in the answer you referenced is a named character, in which the names are the characters: `'1', '2', '3', '4'`. While in the later case you can subset `dict` like this `dict[[as.character(x)]]` (i.e. using the names of the values), in the first case you cannot

Comment: Can I convert "character"" to "Named character"? Any idea how can I bypass this issue?

Comment: why not use the same trick used in the answer you referenced? I mean `dict <- setNames(names(treeList), 1:4)`

Comment: or maybe better yet `dict <- setNames(names(treeList), 1:length(names(treeList)))` in case the length of `treeList` differs