# Color labels of ggdendro plot

Tags: r

I am trying to apply dendextend in order to color the ggdendro  labels. I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.dendrogram") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.dendrogram' applied to an object of class "dendro"
```

Why the conversion does not work? Any idea how to solve it?

Code:

```
library(IncDTW)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro) 
library(dendextend)

A <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 50, ncol = 1)
B <- matrix(1:75, nrow = 75, ncol = 1)
C <- matrix(25:49, nrow = 25, ncol = 1)
D <- matrix(1:50, nrow = 50, ncol = 1)
treeList <- list(A,B,C,D)

names(treeList)[1] <- "A"
names(treeList)[2] <- "B"
names(treeList)[3] <- "C"
names(treeList)[4] <- "D"

result <- dtw_dismat(treeList, dist_method = "norm2", return_matrix = F)
distMatrixResult <- result$dismat
hc <- hclust(distMatrixResult, method = "average")
hc <- dendro_data(hc)
dict <- setNames(names(treeList), 1:length(names(treeList)))
hc$labels$label <- sapply(hc$labels$label, function(x) dict[[as.character(x)]])
ggdendrogram(hc, rotate = TRUE, theme_dendro = FALSE)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc)
d5=color_branches(dend)
plot(d5)
d5g=color_branches(dend,5,groupLabels=TRUE)
plot(d5g)
d5gr=color_branches(dend,5,groupLabels=as.roman)
plot(d5gr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were confusing dendrogram with dendrogram data. This will work:

```
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc)

dict <- setNames(names(treeList), 1:length(names(treeList)))
hc$labels$label <- sapply(hc$labels$label, function(x) dict[[as.character(x)]])
ggdendrogram(dend, rotate = TRUE, theme_dendro = FALSE)

d5=color_branches(dend)
plot(d5)
d5g=color_branches(dend,4,groupLabels=TRUE)
plot(d5g)
d5gr=color_branches(dend,4,groupLabels=as.roman)
plot(d5gr)
```

***Result:***

[image]

#### *Edit:*

As [@maxatSOflow pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54626400/6574038) we can use `usedist::dist_setNames()` to set names to a `"dist"` object. So, to finally get your dendrogram labeled as expected you could do the following.

```
library(IncDTW)
result <- dtw_dismat(treeList, dist_method="norm2", return_matrix=FALSE)
distMatrixResult <- result$dismat

# install.packages("usedist")
library(usedist)
distMatrixResult <- dist_setNames(distMatrixResult, LETTERS[1:4])

hc <- hclust(distMatrixResult, method="average")

library(ggdendro) 
ggdendrogram(hc, rotate=TRUE, theme_dendro=FALSE)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc)


library(dendextend)
d5=color_branches(dend)
plot(d5)
d5g=color_branches(dend,4,groupLabels=TRUE)
plot(d5g)
d5gr=color_branches(dend,4,groupLabels=as.roman)
plot(d5gr)
```

*Gives:*

[image]

***Data:***

```
A <- matrix(1:50, nrow=50, ncol=1)
B <- matrix(1:75, nrow=75, ncol=1)
C <- matrix(25:49, nrow=25, ncol=1)
D <- matrix(1:50, nrow=50, ncol=1)

treeList <- setNames(list(A, B, C, D), LETTERS[1:4])
```

Comment: It works fine but the labels are gone (A,B,C and D). Any idea how to bring them back?

Comment: I don't know. I think they get lost before in the `dtw_dismat(.)` part. When you do `str(result)` can you see any labels?

Comment: No, I can not see them.

Comment: You might be interested in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593845/6574038

Comment: I see, you're running in circles. I've opened a ticket for you on [github](https://github.com/maxar/IncDTW/issues/1).

Comment: Seems it's solved now, please take a look at the edits to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

At the current version of IncDTW you need to append the names after using dtw_dismat(), in future version I'll adjust that. So for now try:

```
result <- dtw_dismat(treeList, dist_method = "norm2", return_matrix = TRUE)
distMatrixResult <- result$dismat
dnames <- LETTERS[1:4]
dimnames(distMatrixResult) <- list(dnames , dnames)
distMatrixResult <- as.dist(distMatrixResult)
```

also have a look at this post:
[ggdendrogram labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593085/ggdendrogram-labels/54626400#54626400)